# Object of type 'System.EventHandler' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler'

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, runtime-error

So I imagine this actually has something to do with my IDE, but I don't know what to do about it.  I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013.

I made a form that is used as an Open File form - it has a directory tree on the left, and on the right, a table displaying info on the files in the selected directory.

At first, this table was a TrueDBGrid from ComponentOne.  But that was giving me some issues, so I finally decided to simply replace it with a regular DataGridView.

This is the beginning of the form's code:

```
Public Class dlgOpenFile

    Private extension() As String       'used for filtering by extension(s) selected in dropdown
    Private list As DataTable
    Private treeTimer As Timer
    Private backStack As New Stack(Of String)
    Private forwardStack As New Stack(Of String)
    Private btnTip As New ToolTip()

    Private Sub dlgOpenFile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        inTextSearch = False
        btnTip.SetToolTip(btnBack, "Backward")
        btnTip.SetToolTip(btnForward, "Forward")
        btnTip.SetToolTip(btnRefresh, "Refresh")
        btnTip.SetToolTip(btnSearch, "Search")
        btnTip.SetToolTip(btnClear, "Clear Search")

        etc....
```

After changing what needed to be changed to work with the new type, I went to run the application from VS - I ended up getting this runtime error

> Object of type 'System.EventHandler' cannot be converted to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler'

At this line:

```
Private btnTip As New ToolTip()
```

So I simply added a ToolTip component to the form in the designer so I could comment out that particular line.  But when I tried it again, I got the same thing, this time at this line:

```
Private forwardStack As New Stack(Of String)
```

So I moved the instantiation of the stacks to the Load event, like so:

```
Private backStack As Stack(Of String)
Private forwardStack As Stack(Of String)

Private Sub dlgOpenFile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    backStack = New Stack(Of String)
    forwardStack = New Stack(Of String)
```

Well, now I get that exact same error, but on the call for that form!  In a different form where a user can click on a button to open this form, on the line:

```
    Dim openFile As New dlgOpenFile
```

I really do not know what I can do about that one.  Why does the error just keep moving up the chain?  Why on earth would I get such an error in such a place?

I tried checking in my code, then closing visual studio for a bit, then reopening it, but that did not change anything.

I have a few different event handlers for dgvList in my code - CellFormatting to set cell tool tips, CellClick and DoubleClick....I don't see why these would be causing problems with just trying to launch the form....

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are manually casting the "DataGridViewCellEventHandler" to your data grid view event.

Look in your code for this. If so do not do that.

Instead, let the system generate the event handler method by itself.

for example, to handle/call something for "datagridview cellValueChanged"

Go to your form.

Select the datagrid view control.

Rightclick->Properties.

In the properties window, select the "events" icon.

Look for "cellValueChanged".
Double click on it.You will something like below created.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged

'Handle your business or function calls.


    End Sub
```

This may fix your issue. If this is not the thing you are looking for, please add a comment, I will delete this answer.

Comment: No, I don't specifically do anything myself with 'DataGridViewCellEventHandler'.  Just to see if for whatever reason your suggestion works, I tried it (so now there's an empty CellValueChanged method in my code) - no change.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like I found the issue:  In the properties for the DataGridView, being that I have the ComponentOne stuff, there's a spot for selecting "C1Command on C1CommandHolder" and a spot for selecting "C1ContextMenu on C1CommandHolder".  I had selected my Print command in the dropdown for C1Command, and my Print context menu in the dropdown for C1ContextMenu.  Turns out I should have left the C1Command as 'none'.  ay ay ay!